# Why DES can be used only with 56bit key? And why the plaintext must be 64 bits in length?

Tags: cryptography, des

Why DES can be used only with 56bit key? What happens if we use the longer key? Also, why the plaintext must be 64 bits in length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

US regulations at the time required users of stronger than 56-bit keys, to submit to "key recovery" to enable law enforcement back-door access.

Thus DES, as a standard, was specified at the maximum allowed key length of 56 bits. If you used a longer key, you would not be compatible with other DES systems.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/56-bit_encryption

If you are implementing a system & have a choice of encryption, more modern & stronger ciphers would be absolutely recommended. The current standard would be AES (Advanced Encryption System) which is widely available, strong and allows key sizes from 128 - 256 bits.

For desktop or server applications, AES-256 would be a good default choice.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

When encrypting data, plaintexts must often be "padded" to a minimum size. Ciphers rely on jumbling and interactions between multiple bits, to preserve secrecy of the plaintext & avoid potentially revealing the key. For a short plaintext without padding, jumbling and interactions are removed as a factor & mathematical complexity drops vastly.

Encrypting just a single character without padding, for example a 'y' or 'n' response, could for example reduce a 2^256 keyspace down to possibly 2^24. That could be cracked in minutes. This would enable an attacker to guess large parts of the key, rapidly break it, and then (worst of all) -- decrypt all other traffic on the channel.

Comment: I am really just starting to learn about cryptography. Thanks. So, 64 bits is a minimum for plain text?

Comment: Also, why does DES work? It's so difficult to understand... I mean using S-box seems like a really bad idea. What if the designers of DES put certain bits, so they could decrypt it very easily..? How do you prove that it's secure? Or it's impossible?

Comment: Btw, if 64 bits is minimum, what happens if I use 101 bit plain text? How are those bits divided?

Comment: Block ciphers (such as DES and AES) always require padding to full blocks. 101 bit plaintext would have to be padded to 2x 64-bit blocks for DES.

Comment: Encryption obviously is "complicated", it has to shuffle and compound the bits in a non-linear way.. otherwise it would be trivial to decrypt! This is the function of the S-boxes. No weaknesses or backdoors are believed to exist here. Read the Wikipedia links I referenced, in particular the _"Best public cryptanalysis"_ summaries in the right sidebar. Both algorithms are "secure" in their design but DES is now obsolete in its key-length & should not be chosen for modern use.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't get how people can come up with "good" S-boxes and how they prove it's secure, but I just probably need to keep reading and I'll get there eventually, let's hope.

Comment: Have a read here: These are some comments from the designers of TwoFish, one of the runners-up to the AES nomination.   https://www.schneier.com/paper-twofish-final.pdf  http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/rijndael-vs-serpent-vs-twofish-general-comparison

Comment: @GregS -- did you not bother to read the Wikipedia link? Looks reasonably authoritative.. __and you don't offer a single reference yourself.__ For a 64-bit block cipher, a 64-bit key would be most intuitive -- and see DES's predecessor, which used a 128-bit key. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer_(cipher)

Comment: That wikipedia article is pure garbage. Perhaps you should the Wikipedia article on DES. Looks authoritative? I guess that's the problem with Wikipedia.

Comment: @GregS -- care to elaborate & share some references? I'm interested to read some further background, if you have links or more detail then please share them.

Comment: Comments are too restrictive for such discussions.

Comment: @GregS -- that's why I asked for links or references. If you do post some later, mention my name with an @ 'at symbol' so I get notified of your comment! Thanks.